# CSS width: as it was originally set by bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap with lots of media queries for responsive design. For a given div, I start using bootstrap's `col` to set width and margin:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3" id="special">
```

But in certain cases and in certain cases only, I want to further add my own styling, as below:

```
@media only screen and (orientation:landscape) and (min-width : 320px) {
  .special {
    width:40%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (orientation:landscape) and (min-width : 768px) {
  .special {
    width:"go back to using bootstrap col";
  }
}
```

My problem as you can see from the above, is that as the media query builds, on the next size up, I'm not sure how to say... go back to using the bootstrap col. I tried `width:auto` and `width:initial` but those did not work

Comment: first of all you should be using #special in css as it is an id attribute not class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It generally a bad idea to alter dimension when you are using a grid system, because that's all grid system is build for.

Simply by reading your example is a little unclear because there are couple conditions in your code:

1. width > 320
2. width > 768
3. width between 320 ~ 768
4. orientation is landscape
5. orientation is not landscape

However, media query is and additional expression for your selector, it will use what you already have if YOU DO NOT SPECIFY the OTHERWISE. so for example

```
/* from bootstrap */
.col-xs-6 {
  width: 10 % ;
}

/* your override */
@media only screen and(orientation: landscape) and(max-width: 768px) {
  #special {
    width: 40%;
  }
}
```

By applying this, div will have width of 40% when device is landscape + width is less then 768px (sorry i can't tell your intention by reading your code), it use col-xs-6 or col-xs-offset-3 otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation and the `max-width` reminder, that's what I ultimately used in the answer

Comment: media query has tricky way for expression: max-width means screen width is less than X; min-width: means screen width is greater than X

Answer (score 0):

Merge them both into one media rule

```
@media only screen and (orientation:landscape) and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 768px) {
  .special {
    width:40%;
  }
}
```

Comment: special is an id not class.

Comment: @DipakParmar - thanks! just noticed that from the other comment. Assuming that's just a problem in the question and not in OP's code.

Comment: it's ok. @potatopeelings

Comment: curious, is the only way of doing this to do the merger? there's no way of doing `width: whatever it was`? I'm asking because i'm thinking of potentially more complex scenarios where merging may be difficult

Comment: @james - not as far as I know. The instant your rule takes priority, it overwrites (for lack of a better word) the bootstrap rule. You can't go back to bootstrap rule - the only thing you can do is have the bootstrap rule *again* to overwrite your rule (note you can however go back to CSS defaults)

Answer (score 0):

Like this: 
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 768px) and (orientation : landscape)